# Java - Why is str.substring(str.length()) an acceptable line of code?

Tags: java, string, substring

To make a long story short, why does Java not throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException for this line of code?

```
str.substring(str.length())
```

Is it just by definition of IndexOutOfBoundsException? To make start/end indices take the same range of values for programming convenience/symmetry? Is it just a decision by Oracle? Is there just a special case under the hood that handles this case with the inclusive start index? Or is there some underlying reason...

I read the documentation and they say it just returns the empty string (""). But I'm wondering if this is something to worry about. Will it ever change? I'm thinking no, but I'd like to hear it from someone else. I have some code that depends on a line like this to work because I use substring and indexOf(...)+1 to split some lines up, and I really don't want to put unnecessary logic around the line of code.

Comment: Well it would be quite a huge decision for Oracle to just destroy backwards compatibility for no reason at all, so I think you're safe.

Comment: Why *would* that code throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?  Its behavior is well and sensibly defined, and well documented (as being to return a reference to an empty `String`).  Java has a strong record of maintaining compatibility in general, and there is no advantage to be gained from making a change here.  I am confident you can rely on this behavior.

Comment: Also consistent with  `List.subList` for example http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)

Answer (score 11):

Here´s the docu of the `substring(beginindex)` javadoc.

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the end of this string.
>
> Examples:
>
> "unhappy".substring(2) returns "happy"
>
> "Harbison".substring(3) returns "bison"
>
> "emptiness".substring(9) returns "" (an empty string)
>
> Parameters:
>   beginIndex the beginning index, inclusive.
>
> Returns:
>   the specified substring.
>
> Throws:
>   IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object.

Basicly because it just throws if `beginindex > length` and will return an empty `String` if `beginindex == length`.

And as @Kayaman pointed out, Oracle wont destroy the backward compatibility to other java version just to change this.

Answer (score 5):

As explained in the java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)), the IndexOutOfBoundsException is throwed only if beginIndex is **negative** or **larger than the length** of this String object.

And also check the below example from the java docs

```
"emptiness".substring(9) returns "" (an empty string)
```

---

As explained in the **comment**, but that is not same for `charAt` method. This method is correct and precise as per the docs and as per the API user point of view.

```
public char charAt(int index) {
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= count)) {     //          >= operator is used
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    }
    return value[index + offset];
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's the one I saw. It still doesn't make sense to me why it would be this way since accessing index x of an array of length x throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and not an empty object, for example. Seems inconsistent to me, but I guess I shouldn't worry. I doubt they'll change something that would destroy backwards compatibility for no reason.

Comment: I just checked any mail discussion related to this issue. but couldnt find related information for that. I'll update once I get it. But from code point of view this method calls `substring(beginIndex,  count)` where count is the number of characters in string/char array. and the overloaded method is checking for condition `if (beginIndex > endIndex) { throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex - beginIndex); }`  it is not **>=**. May be this is due to follow specs, but I'm not sure. Even `str.substring(str.length(), str.length())` works, because of not using >= or <= operator.

Answer (score 5):

You said you already read the docs, so you know it returns empty string because that's what the docs say it will do. But the underlying reason is as follows:

For the purposes of substring, the indices of a string are interpreted as being between the characters in the string. So index 0 is before the first character, index 1 is between the first and second, and index str.length() is after the last character. The substring starting right after the last character is "".

It makes more sense in the two-argument version of substring, where having it defined this way saves you from writing special case logic when pulling out a substring that may or may not include the last character.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot more sense to me, now. I recall some other language I studied a long time ago doing this the same way. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Another way of looking at it is that

```
str.substring(0, x) + str.substring(x)
```

is always going to be equivalent to `s`, where `0 <= x <= str.length()`

For this to break for the single case where `x == str.length()` would be inconsistent and annoying - for example you'd have to write special cases into parsing loops.

See also the [documentation for `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html):

> Thrown by String methods to indicate that an index is either negative or greater than the size of the string. For some methods such as the charAt method, this exception also is thrown when the index is equal to the size of the string.

Note the second sentence - `charAt` *has* to throw an exception when the index is equal to the length of the string because there is no `char` at that position for it to return. But technically there *is* a valid `String` at that position - it's a zero-length `String`, i.e. `""`.

This is consistent with other "slicing" operations in java - for example,

```
list.subList(list.size(), list.size())
```

will return an empty list, rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: Your answer is indeed correct. But why it will be inconsistent/annoying, because the api user will not care about what the underlying implementation is like. But he expects the API to be more precise, meaning calling substring from/to `.length` (which is out of char array) should throw `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @rajuGT the API *is* precise, and documented. The docs clearly state that it throws "`IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if `beginIndex` is negative or *larger than the length* of this String object." There is possibly some argument to throw an exception in the `str.length()` case, but there are also plenty (and IMHO better) arguments for it being the way it is. In the case there isn't a definite right answer, you have to choose one. And then document it. And that's what they did. Also see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html for *when* it is thrown

Comment: @rajuGT or maybe I'm misunderstanding your point... Maybe the difference here is you're not trying to get an array element, but a slice of the array, and a zero-length slice is perfectly fine. Note this is consistent with e.g. `List.subList` - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)

Answer (score 2):

What you propose is not logical. These lines of code

```
System.out.println("1 " + "***".substring(0));
System.out.println("2 " + "***".substring(1));
System.out.println("3 " + "***".substring(2));
System.out.println("4 " + "***".substring(3));
```

produce

```
1 ***
2 **
3 *
4
```

The fourth line of output follows the pattern of the other 3. Throwing an exception would not make any sense.