# Why doesn't this recursive function crash when it reaches s.substring(1) where s="y"?

Tags: java, string

```
public static void recur(String s)
{
    if(s.length() == 0)
        return;
    else
    {
        System.out.println(s.charAt(0));
        recur(s.substring(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should it crash? Have you taken a look at the documentation? Why would you expect it to crash?

Comment: `"y".substring(1)` returns empty string `""` so that will be passed as argument to another recursive call and there `if(s.length() == 0)` will handle it.

Comment: I thought that because the length of the String is 1 and the only index position is 0, s.substrin(1) should not work and it would give a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException as there is no index =1.

Comment: Possibly related: [Java - Why is str.substring(str.length()) an acceptable line of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33547529), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63526268/struggling-with-substring-logic-for-2-character-string-on-codingbat/63526458#63526458

Answer (score 3):

String that is substringed with its own length will return an empty string.

```java
String s = "y";
System.out.println(s.substring(s.length()));
// prints out an empty string
```

So, when calling your recursive function with `"y"`, it will run itself once again with an empty string, and the condition `if (s.length() == 0) return;` will just exit from the function.

---

For details about String in Java, in [the Java 6 Language Specification of 10.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/arrays.html#10.9):

> In the Java programming language, unlike C, an array of char is not a String, and neither a String nor an array of char is terminated by '\u0000' (the NUL character).

Therefore, an empty String in Java is really empty. Getting the character at `String.length()` will always result in string out of bound exception. That is,

```java
String empty = "";
empty.charAt(0); // <= throws exception at runtime
```

Comment: then why does s.charAt(0) does not work? Does java strings also have \0 or \u0000 or the NUL character in the end like C?

Comment: Add detailed elaboration about Java String

Comment: It didn't change between java 6 and today, but [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.9)'s the current spec for reference.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of [`String.substring(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) states

> Throws:
> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object.

Your beginIndex is always 1 (not negative), for an empty string you do not reach this point since the first `if` will already have returned. And for any non-empty string `1` is not larger than the length since the length in that case is by definition >= 1.